# Tensorflow report error with the restored training model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm newbie with machine learning and Tensorflow, by using its example tutorial source code, the model get trained and printed the accuracy, but it doesn't include source code to export the model and variables and import for predict new image.

So I revised the source code to export the model, and create a new python script to predict by using the test data set.

Here is the source code to export the training model:

```
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)
print("run here3")
# Create the model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name="x")
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]), name="W")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
... ignore the source code for the cost function definition and train the model
#after the model get trained, save the variables and y 
tf.add_to_collection('W', W)
tf.add_to_collection('b', b)
tf.add_to_collection('y', y)

saver.save(sess, 'result')
```

In the new python script, I try to restore the model and re-execute the y function

```
sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('result.meta')
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
W = tf.get_collection('W')[0]
b = tf.get_collection('b')[0]
y = tf.get_collection('y')[0]


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data', one_hot=True)
img = mnist.test.images[0]
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images})
```

Everything works correctly, I could get the W and b value if I print them, however I get error while executing the last statement(run y function).

```
Caused by op u'x', defined at:
File "predict.py", line 58, in <module>
tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
File "/Users/zhouqi/git/machine-learning/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "predict.py", line 25, in main
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('result.meta')
File "/Users/zhouqi/git/machine-learning/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site- packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1566, in    import_meta_graph
**kwargs)
File "/Users/zhouqi/git/machine-learning/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 498, in import_scoped_meta_graph
producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
File "/Users/zhouqi/git/machine-learning/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 288, in import_graph_def
op_def=op_def)
File "/Users/zhouqi/git/machine-learning/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2327, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "/Users/zhouqi/git/machine-learning/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1226, in __init__
self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x' with dtype float
[[Node: x = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

It's weird cause I do use the same statement to define x, and feed x using the same approach while executing y function, I don't know why it does not work?

Comment: Why did you replace this line: `mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)` with `mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data', one_hot=True)` ?

Comment: Oh, for the new script I created to restore the model, I simplify it to use the hard coded data folder, FLAGS.data_dir is the same as /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the new placeholder:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
```

Creating a placeholder with the same name is not enough. You actually need the same placeholder that you used when you created the model. Therefore you must also add x to a collection in the first file:

```
tf.add_to_collection('x', x)
```

and load it in the new file:

```
x = tf.get_collection('x')[0]
```

instead of creating a new one.